# Zero set of eigenfunction along a sub manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, laplacian

Let $M$ be a 2-dimensional closed Riemannian manifold and let $$\phi:M\rightarrow M$$ be an isometry with $\phi^2=Id_M$. Consider the fixed point set $$F:=\lbrace x\in M: \phi(x)=x \rbrace\subset M,$$ and
suppose  $F\subset M$ is a closed $1$-dimensional submanifold. Let $u:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an eigenfunction on $M$ for the Laplace-Beltrami operator. Suppose further $u$ is symmetric with respect to the isometry $\phi$, i.e.\ $u\circ \phi=u$.

It follows easily that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}_{\lvert p}=0$ for all $p\in F$, where $\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu}_{\lvert p}\in (T_p F)^{\perp}$ is a perpendicular vector along $F$.

I am wondering if there must be at least one point $p^{*}\in F$ such that $u(p^{*})\neq 0$? Or is it possible that $u$ vanishes everywhere along $F$?

The easy examples suggest the former, but I could not prove it in general. Does anyone has an idea how to approach this problem?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a result of Dong.  See Theorem 3.4.

*Rui-Tao Dong*, [**Nodal sets of eigenfunctions on Riemann surfaces**](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214448750), *J. Differential Geom.* **36** (1992), no. 2, 493--506.

Comment: I think it is much older. By Aronszajn, an eigenfunction $u$ cannot vanish to   infinite order at any point, and in dimension $2$ this implies that near any point the nodal set is $C^1$ equivalent to $Re(z^m)=0$ for some $m\geq 1$. In particular, common zeros of $u$ and $\nabla u$ are isolated, which answers the question.

Comment: @BS.  Thanks, I wasn't sure about the history.  Dong's result gives a nice upper bound on the number of singular points.